# how to keep the colored output of a command after piping it through grep

Tags: bash, colors, grep, pipe

For the example, `systemctl status weechat |grep Active`

The output of systemd  is green or red depending on status.

How to keep that when piping through grep (or other command like tail,...)?

There is --color, but it's not that.

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `script` to keep color :

```
script -qec "systemd status weechat" /dev/null |grep Active
```

Comment: Perfect. 
Except I didn't realize i wrote systemd instead of systemctl. There was no output for sure.. I'm so dumb :-) . Now it's a pretty good looking output .Thank you very much